# Cannot access array elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to go through an array of objects in javascript but no for, forEach loop, of filter function would recognize the array elements. Array length shows as 0. When I log the array variable in Chrome, it does contain in some way the elements I need to go through though and the array length shows as the correct one (6).

[image: Console logging in Chrome]

Any ideas how I can loop through these Drupal.Ajax elements?

Comment: Why don't you share the code instead of a screenshot?

Comment: You've to wait until the array is filled. You see the small blue icon, hover over it, and read the info on the upcoming popup.

Comment: It simply means your array is empty up to the point where you logged the length, but then was filled later when you logged it on the console. If this was done over a network, use Promise or async function to wait for the array elements before looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

As already answered in comments, the array is not filled when you try to operate on it, see the following example:

```
const foo = []
console.log(foo)
foo.push(1)
console.log(foo)

// output
[]
  0: 1
  length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)

[1]
   0: 1
   length: 1
   __proto__: Array(0)
```

Notice the difference in the first line, where chrome outputs the real value of the array:

```
[]
[1]
```

But once you expand the output you can see that chrome evaluates the values and adds a **i** icon that alerts you about this fact.

[image: chrome console]

### Solution

It all depends on your code, since you didn't share any code is hard to advance any solution. But the approach is to be sure that the value of the array is already populated before attempt any operations.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a Promise (or async/wait if you are using ES6+) to wait for the elements to fill the array. This way you never loop over the target array until there is an element in it.

```
let targetArray = [];

let p = new Promise(resolve => {

  // get elements from a file or over the network
  // or the simplest is to just set a small timeout

  resolve(targetArray);
});

p.then(arr => {
  if (arr.length > 0) {

    // loop over arr

  }
});
```

For older vanilla JS callbacks can be used also.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had to execute the code after page load as I didn have control over when the array was actually populated.

Comment: You can use `onload` handler https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload